# Usage of for in these examples

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between following two:

> Wait for a second.
>
> Wait a second.

Why for is used in such sentences? I often see such sentences but can't figure out when for is used and when it isn't. Like

> I studied for two hours.
>
> I studied two hours.

Can we drop preposition "of" in passage below?

> A boy doesn’t show any interest in his work or doesn’t try to do it
>   with any distinction when he is forced to follow a direction mapped
>   out by his parents that runs counter to all ***of*** his interests and
>   abilities.

Answer (score 3):

*For {time-expression}* can appear after a verb or adjective to indicate how long the action was done or how long the attribute described by the adjective lasted.

This is only one of the many meanings of *for*.  Prepositions in English like in many other languages are overloaded with many meanings that you simply have to memorize or follow existing patterns to learn.

> I walked for three hours
>
> I was sad for a long time.

It is also possible to use the time expression as an adverbial clause, where it directly modifies a verb or adjective.  This typically strongly implies that the activity or attribute modified lasted for that long.  It can potentially look a little weird in writing when modifying an adjective but is usually OK in speech.

> I walked three hours.
>
> I was sad a long time.

---

*Of X* means *from group/set named X* or *from a group/set that has one or more X's*, among many other meanings.

Since *all* means *every*, it will automatically reference everything in a group.  So the *of* is optional, but it's not wrong to use it if needed for emphasis, clarity, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The verb **wait** is intransitive: it does not take an object. If we want to specify a time, you have to use the preposition **for** to attach a time to it.

> I waited **for** hours but he didn't come.

If you say [wait a second](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wait-a-minute-moment-second?q=wait%20a%20minute%2Fmoment%2Fsecond) (without **for**), it is an idiomatic expression that is said in order to interrupt someone or to get their attention, or when you have suddenly thought of something important.

You might hear somebody omit the preposition when speaking informally, but this is not grammatically correct.

**study** is a transitive verb whose object is the thing that you study:

> I studied **maths**

So, if you say

> I studied **two hours**

it seems to suggest that you were learning everything about two hours for an unspecified period of time. For study, like with wait, you have to use a preposition to 
specify how long you studied for.

> I studied **for** two hours.

Comment: *Wait* can also be used transitively as in *wait your turn* and *wait a while* or *wait tables*